# utf8 strings and malloc in c

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, malloc

With "opendir" and "readdir" i do read a directories content.
During that process i do some strings manipulation / allocation:
something like that:

```
int stringlength = strlen(cur_dir)+strlen(ep->d_name)+2;
char *file_with_path = xmalloc(stringlength); //xmalloc is a malloc wrapper with some tests (like no more memory)
snprintf (file_with_path, (size_t)stringlength, "%s/%s", cur_dir, ep->d_name);
```

But what if a string contains a two-byte utf8 char?
How do you handle that issue?

```
stringlength*2?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strlen()` counts the bytes in the string, it doesn't care if the contained bytes represent UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters. So, for example, `strlen()` of a string containing an UTF-8 encoding of "aöü" would return `5`, since the string is encoded as `"a\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc"`.

Comment: For completeness' sake, it might be worth pointing out that a UTF-8 encoded string will never contain a byte with the value 0, i.e. it remains a valid string from C's string function's point of view, although they will count bytes as characters.

Comment: Huh? Sure, an UTF-8 encoded C string will not contain a NUL byte. But that says nothing of UTF-8 in general.

Comment: @Per: UTF-8 in general doesn't contain NUL bytes, the encoding is made that way.

Comment: Alright, I guess what you mean is that it doesn't contain a NUL byte for anything else than to indicate a NUL character. That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` counts the number of bytes in a string (up to the terminating NUL), not the number of UTF-8 characters, so `stringlength` should already be as large as you need it.